# Rearrange a dataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am on a code in python and I would like to transform this dataFrame :

Before:

[image]

Into this DataFrame :

[image]

I tried to pivot the table with the command :

```
pd.pivot_table(mytable, index = [JAN, FEB, MAR])
```

But I am not satisfied by the result...

Comment: please show the code instead of pictures for input and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Word'], value_vars=['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR']).dropna()
df = df.pivot(index='variable', columns='value', values='Word')
```